# Laravel app with subapp project config and architecture

Tags: laravel

I have 2 apps that I've build with laravel. For now those apps are running in itself domain like app1.com and app2.com, For the reqs those apps needs to be merged to one superapp. the domain app1.com gonna be the domain.

The folder structure like below:

```
App1
   > app
   > public
   ...
   > * app1 laravel folders
   ...
   > subapp
      > App2
         > app
         > public
         ...
         > * app2 laravel folders
         ...
```

I have tried so many configs in `.htaccess` to access the subapp for app2 in app1.com/app2 but it keeps giving me 500 or 404 errors.

Am I missing something? How to make it possible?

Comment: what is your purpose of doing this?

Comment: I want to access those 2 apps with just single domain name app1.com, every other apps except app1 can be access from first segment of url like app1.com/app2